# Finding If A linear Transformation Exists

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as followed:
>   $$T\begin{pmatrix} 
> 3 \\
> 2\\
> 5
> \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 \\
> 3\\
> 2
> \end{pmatrix},T\begin{pmatrix} 
> 2 \\
> 2\\
> 5
> \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 0 \\
> 1\\
> 0
> \end{pmatrix},T\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 \\
> 1\\
> 3
> \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 0 \\
> 1\\
> 1
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> If there such a linear transformation find it

What I have done is to to set $$T= \begin{pmatrix} 
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
h & k & l
\end{pmatrix}$$

And create linear equations to find that

$$T= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 0\\
2 & -4 & 1\\
2 & -7 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

But $\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
3\\
2
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and by knowing how the linear transformation work on a basis we can find how it work on any vector, but how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u_1 = \pmatrix{3\\2\\5},u_2 = \pmatrix{2\\2\\5}, u_3=\pmatrix{1\\1\\3}\\
u_1 - u_2 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$

$T\pmatrix{1\\0\\0} = Tu_1 - Tu_2$

Now find $T\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$ and $T\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$ and you will have your matrix (in the standard basis.)

Now it would be an option to make $u_1,u_2, u_3$ the basis then you would have to find what $Tu_1,Tu_2, Tu_3$ looks like in this basis.

Or you could make $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\3\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 \\
1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ your basis as you suggest but then you will need to find what $u_1, u_2, u_3$ look like in this basis.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Verify if $\begin{bmatrix} v_1, v_2, v_3\end{bmatrix}$ is non-singular (or check if $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is linearly independent). If it is then such linear transfomation $T$ exists. Given any vector $x$, we can express them as $x=\sum_{i=1}^3 \alpha_iv_i$ and hence $T(x)=\sum_{i=1}^3 \alpha_iT(v_i)$. In particular, you can let $x$ be the standard unit vector.

If it is singular, then you have to check for consistency, let say we found that $v_3=\sum_{i=1}^2 \beta_i v_i$, then you have to verify that $T(v_3)=\sum_{i=1}^2 \beta_i T(v_i)$ for such linear transformation to exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have 9 variables in your matrix $T$ and if you multiply $T$ by the vectors in your definition then you will find that you have 9 equations. With a little algebra you can find all 9 elements of $T$.